# Dynamically create a function in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I found this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rK7tJ/72/) and I want to sort of merge it with [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/fr5rw3a8/5/). So when you click the button 3 times, they each have id 0, 1, 2 respectively. I then want to be able to hide the values of selected options from the other select elements. I tried to dynamically create the function from the working example but didn't manage to do it. Any help would be appreciated!

First fiddle;

JavaScript

```
$("#first").change(function() {
    if($("#first").val() != "none") {
        $("#second option[value!="+$("#first").val()+"]").show();
        $("#second option[value="+$("#first").val()+"]").hide();
    } else {
        $("#second option[value!="+$("#first").val()+"]").show();
    }
});

$("#second").change(function() {
    if($("#second").val() != "none") {
        $("#first option[value!="+$("#second").val()+"]").show();
        $("#first option[value="+$("#second").val()+"]").hide();
    } else {
        $("#first option[value!="+$("#second").val()+"]").show();
}
});
```

HTML

```
<select id="first">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="one">Toyota</option>
    <option value="two">Nissan</option>
    <option value="three">Dodge</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="one">Toyota</option>
    <option value="two">Nissan</option>
    <option value="three">Dodge</option>
</select>
```

Second fiddle;

JavaScript

```
arrSelects = [];

function generateSelect() {
    var para = document.createElement("select");
    $(para).attr('class', 'selectClass');
    $(para).attr('id', arrSelects.length);
    document.getElementById("createHere").appendChild(para);
    arrSelects.push(' ');
    fillSelect();
}

function fillSelect() {
    $( ".selectClass").each( function () {
        if ($(this).has('option').length < 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                $(this).append('<option value='+i+'>'+i+'</option> ');
            }
        }
    })
}
```

HTML

```
<button onclick="generateSelect()" onclick="generateFunction()">Click Me!</button>
<div id="createHere"></div>
```

Comment: `<button onclick="generateSelect()" onclick="generateFunction()">` two `onclick`. Maybe, `onclick="generateSelect();generateFunction()"`

Comment: Ah, yes i believe this is true, but i still can't manage to dynamically create the functions (merge the codes together)